# Login on Checkout not working

Tags: magento-1.9

On my hosting not working Login block on Checkout page. After login it redirect on same page. I tested on my local environment - all works fine. I have saw that on hosting not enter into two IF blocks in CustomerController (line 220):

```
if (!$session->getAfterAuthUrl()) {
   $session->setAfterAuthUrl($session->getBeforeAuthUrl());
}
if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
   $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($session->getAfterAuthUrl(true));
}
```

I used Magento 1.9.2.0. I have upgraded to 1.9.2.4, but it not help.

Comment: Can you login elsewhere on your site? Is this specifically affecting checkout login?

Comment: Customer login is working fine. Login on the checkout page is not working